# Recognizing and using hypergeometric function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

Some expressions that interest me end up having something to do with hyper geometric function. I want to be able to derive such results myself. Where do I begin?

For example, the equation

$$ X''(x)\frac{ \left(e^{-\frac{x}{\epsilon }}+1\right)}{e^{-\frac{x}{\epsilon }}+2}+\frac{l^2}{c^2} X(x)=0$$

is solved by mathematica as

$$c_2 l^{-\frac{2 i l \epsilon }{c}} \left(l^2 e^{x/\epsilon }\right)^{\frac{i l \epsilon }{c}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{i l \epsilon }{c}-\frac{i \sqrt{2} l \epsilon }{c},\frac{\sqrt{2} i l \epsilon }{c}+\frac{i l \epsilon }{c};\frac{2 i l \epsilon }{c}+1;-e^{x/\epsilon }\right)+c_1 l^{\frac{2 i l \epsilon }{c}} \left(l^2 e^{x/\epsilon }\right)^{-\frac{i l \epsilon }{c}} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i l \epsilon }{c}-\frac{i \sqrt{2} l \epsilon }{c},\frac{i \sqrt{2} l \epsilon }{c}-\frac{i l \epsilon }{c};1-\frac{2 i l \epsilon }{c};-e^{x/\epsilon }\right)$$

Is it reasonable to expect doing this by hand?

Comment: Generally the process is to remove the complicated exponential by letting $t = e^{x/\epsilon}$ which yields $X(x) \to X(t)$. Then make the transformation $X(t) = t^{\mu} \, f(t)$ where $\mu$ is a form to be determined such that a reduction is made to the equation desired and $f(t)$ will be the function satisfying the hypergeometric equation.